# HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

My code works if I fill the all the parameters. But when I tried to make 2 of them optional I'm getting...

> HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
>   Type Status Report
>
> Message Request method 'GET' not supported
>
> Description The method received in the request-line is known by the
>   origin server but not supported by the target resource.

COntroller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/testCase" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadTestCase(HttpSession session,@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile file,@RequestParam("testName") String testName,@RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam(value = "paramName", required = false) String[] paramNames,@RequestParam(value = "amountOfInputs", required = false) int amountOfInputs) {
    String user = session.getAttribute("loggedUser").toString();
    return TestCase.addTestCase(testName,type,file,amountOfInputs,paramNames,user);
}
```

Ajax

```
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('creationForm'));
     $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
        url: '/upload/testCase',
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {

    }
```

What's the problem here? I want `paramNames` and `amountOfInputs` optional. All the others are being filled.

Comment: Are you sure the code you've posted in the question matches what is being executed? Your JS sample is clearly sending a POST request, yet the error is stating that the server is  receiving a GET.

Comment: Also check your server's code, maybe those parameters are not optionals